# OSX App Bundle not starting

Tags: xcode, macos, app-bundle

I have a problem with a Mac OSX app bundle.
If I want to run my app bundle nothing happens (double clicking `myApp.app`).

I can run the app by executing `./myApp.app/Contents/MacOS/myApp` without any problem.

The directory structure:

```
myApp.app/
    Contents/
        Info.plist
        PkgInfo
        Resources/
        Frameworks/
        MacOS/
            myApp
```

My `Info.plist`:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE plist PUBLIC "-//Apple//DTD PLIST 1.0//EN" "http://www.apple.com/DTDs/PropertyList-1.0.dtd">
<plist version="1.0">
<dict>
    <key>CFBundleDevelopmentRegion</key>
    <string>en</string>
    <key>CFBundleExecutable</key>
    <string>myApp</string>
    <key>CFBundleIconFile</key>
    <string>icon</string>
    <key>CFBundleIdentifier</key>
    <string>com.whatever.test</string>
    <key>CFBundleInfoDictionaryVersion</key>
    <string>6.0</string>
    <key>CFBundleName</key>
    <string>${PRODUCT_NAME}</string>
    <key>CFBundlePackageType</key>
    <string>APPL</string>
    <key>CFBundleShortVersionString</key>
    <string>1.0.0</string>
    <key>CFBundleSignature</key>
    <string>com.whatever.test</string>
    <key>CFBundleVersion</key>
    <string>1.0.0</string>
    <key>LSMinimumSystemVersion</key>
    <string>${MACOSX_DEPLOYMENT_TARGET}</string>
    <key>NSHumanReadableCopyright</key>
    <string>Copyright © 2014. All rights reserved.</string>
</dict>
</plist>
```

**Edit:**

Console.app result:

```
08.02.14 16:30:45,041 com.apple.launchd.peruser.501[1077]: (com.whatever.test.72544[20350]) Job failed to exec(3) for weird reason: 13
08.02.14 16:30:45,043 Finder[1094]: 8837325: Attempting to SIGCONT to pid #20350 failed, with errno=#3, or the process failed to actually start
08.02.14 16:30:45,046 Dock[1091]: no information back from LS about running process LSASN:{hi=0x0;lo=0x168168}
```

Comment: when you launch the app by double clicking on it, what does "`Console.app`" (found in "`/Application/Utilities`") say?

Comment: I edited my question with the result

Comment: Yes, i remove my comment because, this not the source of the problem, I tested it, and even with unprocessed values for `LSMinimumSystemVersion`, the application launch.

Comment: What is the access rights of the binary ? owner ? group ?

Comment: `-rwxr-xr-x  1 Bastl  staff  4535516  8 Feb 15:48 myApp`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It was a working directory problem. using `getcwd` while executing "myApp.app" gives `/`

I fixed it by using the bundle dir instead of `getcwd`:

```
#include <CoreFoundation/CoreFoundation.h>

std::string getBundleDir()
{
    CFBundleRef mainBundle = CFBundleGetMainBundle();
    CFURLRef resourcesURL = CFBundleCopyResourcesDirectoryURL(mainBundle);
    char path[PATH_MAX];
    if (!CFURLGetFileSystemRepresentation(resourcesURL, TRUE, (UInt8 *)path, PATH_MAX))
        return "";

    CFRelease(resourcesURL);

    chdir(path);

    return path;
}
```

Comment: Can i ask how you detected the problem , Like what was the way to know where the error was or the failed job was ?

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you have your code properly signed, given you're missing a `_CodeSignature` directory. Thus `GateKeeper` may be blocking the code from running.

You have two options:

- Code sign your code.
- <kbd>Control</kbd>click the app bundle and then choose `Open` - it'll bypass the code signature check.

Comment: Yes, the code is not signed. But using the `control` key does also not work. The interesting thing is: sometimes I can see a white window for ~0.5 seconds

Answer (score 0):

This line:

```
08.02.14 16:30:45,041 com.apple.launchd.peruser.501[1077]: (com.whatever.test.72544[20350]) Job failed to exec(3) for weird reason: 13
```

Is leading me to think that you have a `Permission Denied` problem based on this man page:

https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Darwin/Reference/ManPages/man2/intro.2.html

Comment: Any hint for solving this issue?

Comment: @Bastl - I think we'd need to see the actual code that's running to give you better help. I'm wondering if maybe launching the executable directly rather than through the bundle is somehow giving it more privileges than it would otherwise have.

Comment: I don't think that posting the code would be a great idea, because its a very huge project :)

Comment: @Bastl - Post the relevant code. The fact you're getting permission denied likely means that there's a file read or write operation involved. The fact it happens near the start means it happens in code which is run near the start of your project. Possibly you should add some debug messages throughout your code so that you can narrow down where the bug is occurring - they'll be sent to Console.

Comment: @Bastl It' seems that's a permission issue, removing exec for other : `-rwxr-xr--  1 root  wheel` on a test application give the same error. But yours are correct for a newly compiled app.

Comment: I have found the problem: It was a working dir problem. Thanks for your hints.